# How to know the F-Stop in a Webcam?

Tags: aperture, depth-of-field, webcam

I'm looking for a Webcam with large aperture and shallow depth of field, similar to the F 1.8 Canon lenses, so far It has been really difficult since most of the specifications for any webcam are meant for home users.

Please give your thoughts.

Comment: Note that a large aperture means a shallow depth of field, not a large one.  Also note that due to the small sensor size, a shallow depth of field will be near impossible.

Comment: Can you explain little bit more about what you are trying to accomplish here? Why do you want such a thing?

Comment: I do video casting with green screen, and it does help tremendously having large aperture to diffuse the green screen (color evenness) and clarity at night with inexpensive lighting equipment. Also editing time is reduced since I wouldn't have to re-sync audio and video or import files from the DSLR to my computer.

Comment: Looks like a better question for our [Audio-Video Prodiction](http://avp.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: @Gabriel - Please include the info from your comment in your question. As it is your question is about a webcam, but instead you really ask for a **videocamera** that has the ability to live-feed directly to computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webcams typically have rather small image sensors. Whatever the aperture they have is still going to have deep if not infinite depth of field.

Therefore I'd suggest you try instead to find a real camera that allows using it as a webcam. Point-and-shoot type of cameras still usually have a rather small image sensor, but the depth of field is not so readily up to infinity, especially when focused as near as webcams typically are focused (if there is a focus function on a typical webcam).

For a system camera level of shallow depth-of-field you'll really need a system camera, for example a Canon dSLR and that f/1.8 lens you mentioned.